# Why is Spring Security not working?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to integrate Spring Security in my project.

I have followed the documentation given here:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Instead of Spring Boot, I have configured everything using XML.

My `web.xml` is:

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

`dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.name.ot" />

<bean id="resolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

And my view controller is:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController{

    @RequestMapping(value={"/", "/home"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView home() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("home");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value={"/hello"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView hello() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("hello");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value={"/login"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("login");
        return model;
    }
}
```

My security class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

But, I am able to access all the pages, `/`, `/home`, `/hello`, `/login`.

I don't want the user to directly access `/hello`, without going in `/login`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, I am using 3.0 I am not sure how do I use this Filter Chain Proxy in my app, can you give me an example code for my app ?

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue.

My solution is as mentioned in the "Spring in action" book by Craig Walls p247. You need to create an empty class that extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.

```
public class SecurityWebInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {}
```

Answer (score 9):

You have to register [Filter Chain Proxy](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#filter-chain-proxy).

For XML configuration, see [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#delegating-filter-proxy):

> When using servlet filters, you obviously need to declare them in your `web.xml`, or they will be ignored by the servlet container. In Spring Security, the filter classes are also Spring beans defined in the application context and thus able to take advantage of Spring’s rich dependency-injection facilities and lifecycle interfaces. Spring’s `DelegatingFilterProxy` provides the link between `web.xml` and the application context.
>
> When using `DelegatingFilterProxy`, you will see something like this in the `web.xml` file:
>
> ```xml
> <filter>
>     <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
>     <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
> </filter>
>
> <filter-mapping>
>     <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
>     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
> </filter-mapping>
> ```

For Java configuration and Servlet API 3+, see [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer):

> The next step is to register the `springSecurityFilterChain` with the war. This can be done in Java Configuration with Spring’s `WebApplicationInitializer` support in a Servlet 3.0+ environment. Not suprisingly, Spring Security provides a base class `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` that will ensure the `springSecurityFilterChain` gets registered for you.