# Spring security filter is never invoked

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to implement a Spring security filter as follows:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
open class OpenApiConfigurer : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.addFilter(object : FilterSecurityInterceptor() {
            override fun doFilter(request: ServletRequest, response: ServletResponse, chain: FilterChain?) {
                super.doFilter(request, response, chain)
            }
        })
    }
    ...
}
```

I can confirm the `@Configuration` is loaded because, the `configure` method is invoked and the filter is added. However the method `doFilter` is never invoked – I can call whichever requests, but it never does anything inside of it.

What might be wrong? Do I need to do something special?

Comment: Is this Kotlin? If yes, please add a language tag. Is it possible that the way Kotlin compiles to JVM is the reason? Can you test in pure Java?

Comment: I tried pure Java, but the same: https://gist.github.com/knyttl/dd01ee7bd0f157c66786f98e9baba793 - the `http.addFilter` is called but `doFilter` never – therefore this issue is not related to Kotlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason was following:

```kotlin
// Even though this class is not a bean/service/configuration, it must be defined for
// the Spring-Security to work - otherwise the filters are never invoked with no error.
open class SecurityInitializer : AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, which was fixed by adding an implementation of the AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer (see: [Why is Spring Security not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39588934/why-is-spring-security-not-working/43442322#43442322)).